# Excel VBA application.calculate and its variations do not calculate Formula Arrays but F9 key does

Tags: vba, excel, array-formulas, calculation

If have a small range containing a relatively long formula array (see below).
When I calculate the range with **application.calculate or any of its variations** the values are not calculated (nothing is returned) but when I make the cells "dirty" and press [F9], the values are calculated and displayed.

Is there a way to make **application.calculate or any of its variations** mimic [F9] exactly?

Formula Array:

`=IFNA(INDEX(INDEX(rangename_003,,COLUMN(rangename_004)),MATCH(ROW(rangename_004),IF(INDEX(rangename_003,,COLUMN(rangename_004))="",-1,COUNTIF(INDEX(rangename_003,,COLUMN(rangename_004)),"<"&INDEX(rangename_003,,COLUMN(rangename_004)))+1),0)),"")`

Comment: @charleswilliams one for you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a range object referencing the array formula then 
If you are in Manual Calculation mode try

```
theRange.CurrentArray.Calculate
```

If you are in Automatic mode try

```
theRange.CurrentArray.Dirty
theRange.CurrentArray.Calculate
```

Comment: None of the [rangename].calculate or application.calculate work. The [F9] key works perfectly well. Even after the calculations have been done successfully with [F9] and subsequently the application.calculate code is being executed, the values disappear again.

Comment: Works OK for me: what is the refersto of rangename_003 and rangename_004, and what is the cell address of the array formula?

Comment: For example: rangename_004 is "A1:E5" and doesn't contain any data and is only used to retrieve relative column and row numbers, rangename_003 is "G10:K14" and contains the data to be sorted. The formula range is "M10:Q14".

Comment: Thanks: that allows me to duplicate the problem - I agree all forms of Calculate fail the IFNA function. I don't see a bypass at the moment.

Comment: I deducted that application.calculation doesn't fully calculate the formula. When I breakdown the formula is seems to stop within the INDEX formula after the [column_num] section. Is looks like it handles the standard Excel formulas similar as it does UDF formulas and can stop executing mid calculation. Thanks for the effort.